# Declaring array of byte as public member

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I am developing a windows phone 8 app and I need to pass array of byte from background agent to foreground app.

To achieve this, I am writing an interface in C++/CX which will be implemented in C# and will be called back by the background process.

Interface is declared as :

```
public interface class IStatusListener
{
   void OnNewData(byte data[], int length);
};
```

But I get an error like

> "signature of public member contains native type 'byte []'"

How do I declare an array of bytes here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by re-writing the interface :

```
public interface class IStatusListener
{
   void OnNewData(Platform::Array<byte>^* data);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your public WinRT classes cannot use non-RT types in their public signature. This is something people run into very frequently when they start writing WinRT components. For example, see the code below.

```
class Native { };

public ref class MyRef sealed
{
private:
        voidFoo1(Native n) { } // <--This is fine

public:
        voidFoo2(Native n) { } // <--This won't compile
};
```

Comment: I see, but your answer doesn't specify the work around.